# Probabilistic selection from a set

Tags: perl, math, random, statistics

Suppose I want to randomly select a number n between 0 and 30, where the distribution is arbitrary, and not uniform. Each number has a corresponding weight P(n): P(0) = 5, P(1) = 1, P(2) = 30, P(3) = 25, and so on and so forth. How do I do a random selection from this set, such that the probability of selecting a number is proportional to its weight?

What is this type of random selection even called?

I can see one way of implementing it:

1. Make a lookup table V where V(n) = V(n-1) + P(n); with base case V(0) = P(0).
2. Generate a random number X with a uniform distribution between 0 and the maximum value of V.
3. Find the smallest value of n such that V(n) > X.

Is something like this already implemented in a library? (Using Perl.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a very popular problem, and is called *weighted random selection* (or sometimes *weighted random choice*). Here's [a complete article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/) about it.

Comment: Ah! Those keywords are exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to find an existing CPAN module for this (although it's not too popular): List::Util::WeightedChoice

http://search.cpan.org/~dsadinoff/List-Util-WeightedChoice-0.06/lib/List/Util/WeightedChoice.pm

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @p = map { ($_) x int(1 + rand 50) } 0 .. 30;
my @s = @p[ map rand @p, 1 .. 10 ];
print "@s\n";
```